# KOMA footnote style and Bigfoot footnote style

Tags: luatex, koma-script, bigfoot

I have a document with the standard footnote command that I changed with `KOMA-Script` commands. The problem is that this standard style is transferred to my new level of footnotes created with `bigfoot` package. I do not want that, I just want to get the "normal" paragraph style for the second level.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\deffootnote{0em}{1em}{%
    \makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
}

\deffootnotemark{%
    \textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
%\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[roman]

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}} Aenean non neque commodo lectus porta laoreet.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Donec eget vestibulum erat, ut semper felis. Sed faucibus, nisi vitae tincidunt mollis, augue nulla laoreet nibh, vel auctor mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  risus consequat tellus. Vestibulum\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  sed felis vestibulum eros faucibus lacinia quis ac\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  lorem. Pellentesque pulvinar\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  rutrum risus quis accumsan. Nullam interdum hendrerit\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  erat vel porttitor.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Suspendisse venenatis laoreet venenatis. Quisque luctus erat at lorem malesuada,\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  nec dapibus est tincidunt. Fusce a arcu nibh. Donec pretium massa sit amet\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  ultricies rhoncus.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Nulla vestibulum lacinia nisl, bibendum tincidunt neque viverra non. Mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  viverra tellus et metus convallis suscipit id in nisi. Mauris\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  nec libero ac\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  leo pharetra varius. Vestibulum suscipit, enim sed\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  molestie consectetur, libero\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  metus\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  finibus nulla,\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  pellentesque semper sapien orci id tortor. Morbi dignissim sem velit\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}} , non convallis odio\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  tincidunt vitae.\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  Nullam vitae\footnote{here a footnote\footnoteA{where???}}  justo posuere, sagittis purus eu, blandit tellus.
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

If I put the `para*` option in `bigfoot`, i.e., `\usepackage[para*]{bigfoot}` I get this:

[image]

The output that I want is the "simple" paragraph style (for the second level), like this:

[image]

Comment: multiple, nested footnotes  aren't easy and bigfoot is a quite complex package. I wouldn't complicate things by using also the KOMA  redefinitions..

Comment: How could I do the KOMA-style in bigfoot only?